# Ignore all subdirectories except one in .gitignore

Tags: javascript, git, gitignore

I am trying to setup gitignore to exclude all subdirectories except for 2. I have included ~!~ for the two i want to include but Sourcetree does not pick it up.

Here is my relevant gitignore

```
# .gitignore
node_modules/
wp-content/plugins/
wp-content/upgrade/
!wp-content/plugins/export-tool
!wp-content/plugins/darwin_checkout_tracking
```

The two files were set to be included just not. Before they were excluded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /* is important, you must do:

```
# .gitignore
node_modules/
wp-content/plugins/*
wp-content/upgrade/*
!wp-content/plugins/export-tool
!wp-content/plugins/darwin_checkout_tracking
```

And it works

Comment: if `export-tool` and `darwin_checkout_tracking` are subdirectories, shouldn't they end with `/` too?

Comment: No, it's not necessary (I think)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
# .gitignore
!wp-content
node_modules/
wp-content/plugins/*
wp-content/upgrade/*
!wp-content/plugins/export-tool
!wp-content/plugins/darwin_checkout_tracking
```